# Infopath 2010 - Date and time not aligning when submitted to email

Tags: infopath

i have a simple infopath form that is submitting to an email. when the date/time is submitted, the date is on a slightly different horizontal line than the time. i've adjusted margins and padding to no avail. has anyone else seem and fixed this? it's making me crazy! :)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This may happen sometimes on lists when you are customizing list with default template. Best way is to create your own template and add fields on it.